# Printing specific parts of a function for Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning to program in python. I am trying to build a basic program that will output how many of each type of coin (quarter, nickel, dime, penny) based off of what number the user inputs. I currently have it so that it will print a 0. However, I'd like it to omit those values in the `print` statement. I'm not sure how to do that without making each of the different total values and having them print each off of an if statement.

```
#for if statement and to ask for what coin number it is
y = 1
#asks user for how many coins 
x = int(input("How much change are you trying to give (in cents)? "))
while(y <= 1):
    q = 25
    d = 10
    n = 5
    p = 1
    #Take total and divide by 25 as many times as you can output as quarter
    totalq = x // 25
    #Take total from that and divide by 10 as many times as you can and output as dime
    totald = (x-(q*(totalq))) // 10
    #Take total from above and divide by 5 as many times as you can and output as nickel
    totaln = (x-(q*(totalq))-(d*(totald))) //5
    #Finally take total from above and see how many is left over and output as penny
    totalp = (x-(q*(totalq))-(d*(totald))-(n*(totaln))) // 1
    y = y + 1
    total = (str(totalq) +" quarters " + str(totald) +" dimes " + str(totaln) +" nickels " + str(totalp) + " pennies")

    print(total)
```

Comment: I've corrected the indentation in your code. Keep in mind that Python is sensitive to indentation, and so it's helpful if you make sure that all your indentation gets reproduced correctly when you copy your code into a post here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might find [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23087560/3001761) helpful; `make_change` is close to what you are attempting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to approach this is, as you suggest, using a bunch of `if`s - something like:

```
if totalq:
    print(totalq, "quarters", end=' ')
if totald:
    print(totalq, "dimes", end=' ')
if totaln:
    print(totalq, "nickels", end=' ')
if totalp:
    print(totalq, "pennies")
```

Or, you could make this a little less repetitive using a generator expression:

```
pairs = [(totalq, 'quarters'),
         (totald, 'dimes'),
         (totaln, 'nickels'),
         (totalp, 'pennies')]
total = ' '.join(str(value) + ' ' + name
                 for value, name in pairs
                 if value)
print(total)
```

Personally, I think the latter approach is prettier, but it's also a bit more complicated. If there's something about this latter code you don't understand, let me know.